# Are questions about music competition ruling on topic here?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I want to ask a question about why [no first prize was awarded](https://theviolinchannel.com/sendai-international-violin-competition-2019-violinist-shannon-lee-2nd-prize-no-1st-prize/) at Japan’s Sendai International Violin Competition this year. Is this the right place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Often, questions in music that ask "why" are not a good fit here as we don't know the composer's mind. But this feels like it might be on topic - there is probably published justification for it.

Comment: [I have asked](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/86497/38312). Thanks for your reply!

Comment: May I ask why you think it's on-topic here? It's not specifically about practising an instrument. Thus, I would've expected it's a better fit for MusicFans. But I might be missing something :)

Comment: @Arsak it's one of those where it's going to depend on what the answer actually is. If they didn't award a first prize because they lost the first prize, that's got little to do with musical practice. But if they didn't award it because of some particular criteria that might be of wider or general interest, then that does relate to musical practice. Hopefully someone knows the answer!

Comment: @topomorto thank you. I only thought about competition regulation in general, not about the performing aspects.

Comment: My best guess is that depending on the answer, it may or may not be on-topic. If the answer is something like "no performers showed up", the post doesn't really belong here. If it's something musical, like "well, the reverb of the competition area was affected by the recent weather system in the area, making the violins impossible to judge", I think it might be alright.